# Host : Debian 11 / VM : MacOS Monterey

Tags: debian, virtualbox, macos

I try to use virtualbox into Debian 11 with gnome to virtualize a MacOS VM, but it is very slow.

What could I do to optimize VM or variables.

Thanks.

Comment: Usage of Apple software/OS in a VM is allowed ONLY in Apple hardware.

Comment: I understand, but I want to try XCode to make application before buying an Apple.

Comment: I try another VM with macos 12.6.2 and it is running, but XCode simulator crashes.